# WSO2 Governance Registry with UDDI

Tags: wso2, uddi, juddi, wso2-esb

I´m using WSO2 Governance Registry 4.5.1.

I want to use UDDI, I download the version WSO2 Governance Registry 4.5.1 and I followed de instruction here http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance450/Support+for+UDDI but I get the next error:

```
    [2012-12-06 17:11:13,635]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.DeploymentInter
    ceptor} -  Deploying Axis2 service: UDDIReplicationService {super-tenant}
    [2012-12-06 17:11:16,220] **ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.uddi.servlet.JUDDIRegi
    stryServlet} -  jUDDI registry could not be started.java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBou
    ndsException: 0**
    org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOut
    OfBoundsException: 0
        at org.apache.juddi.config.AppConfig.getPersistentConfiguration(AppConfig.java:122)
        at org.apache.juddi.config.AppConfig.loadConfiguration(AppConfig.java:95)
        at org.apache.juddi.config.AppConfig.<init>(AppConfig.java:62)
        at org.apache.juddi.config.AppConfig.getInstance(AppConfig.java:183)
        at org.apache.juddi.config.AppConfig.getConfiguration(AppConfig.java:205)
        at org.apache.juddi.Registry.start(Registry.java:55)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.uddi.servlet.JUDDIRegistryServlet.init(JUDDI
RegistryServlet.java:25)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.init(Se
rvletRegistration.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.registerServle
t(ProxyServlet.java:142)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.HttpServiceImpl.registerSer
vlet(HttpServiceImpl.java:59)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.servlet.internal.RegistryAtomServiceComponen
t.registerJUDDIServlet(RegistryAtomServiceComponent.java:96)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.servlet.internal.RegistryAtomServiceComponen
t.setJUDDIRegistryServlet(RegistryAtomServiceComponent.java:123)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Do I forget any step?

Any suggestion???

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using Governance Registry 4.5.3 instead. 4.5.1 version did have some limitations which is probably why you are seeing this. However, even in 4.5.3, there are a few known issues which would impact certain UDDI operations, but most of the UDDI functionality is working in 4.5.3.

Thanks,
Senaka.